# Errors when executing form through WAMP

Tags: php, forms

Hello fellow users of Stack,

I am trying to create an online order form. The form is supposed have buttons to update the totals for the quantities entered and also to submit the order. Whenever I execute the script through WAMP I am returned with a page displaying some errors and the update does not seem to be working and I cannot figure out why. Hopefully someone can point out what exactly I am doing wrong. The following are the errors that WAMP lists:

> Notice: Undefined index: brady_price in C:\wamp\www\shop.php on line
>   31
>
> Notice: Undefined index: james_price in C:\wamp\www\shop.php on line
>   32
>
> Notice: Undefined index: edelmen_price in C:\wamp\www\shop.php on line
>   33
>
> Notice: Undefined index: price in C:\wamp\www\shop.php on line 34
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\wamp\www\shop.php on line 35

```
  <?php
    $Brady_Jersey = $_POST["brady_price"];
    $James_Jersey = $_POST["james_price"];
    $Edelmen_Jersey = $_POST["edelmen_price"];
    $price = $_POST["price"];
    $Quantity = $_POST["Quantity"];
    $totalqty = 0;
    $total = 0.00;
    $total = $price * $Quantity;
    echo "the total is ". $total;
    echo "<P>Order Processed.";
    echo date("H:i, jS F");
    echo "<br>";
    ?>
    <form action="shop.php" method="post">
    <table class="display" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <th> Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brady Jersey</td>
        <td>$85.00<input type="hidden" name="brady_price" value="3" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="brady_qty" /></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>James Jersey</td>
        <td>$85.00<input type="hidden" name="james_price" value="4" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="james_qty" /></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Edelmen Jersey</td>
        <td>$75.00<input type="hidden" name="edelmen_price" value="4" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="edelmen_qty"/></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Irving Jersey</td>
        <td>$75.00<input type="hidden" name="irving_price" value="4" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="irving_qty"</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="total">Total: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="total" value="0" readonly="readonly" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: " ...a page displaying some errors..."

Comment: You should add the error messages to your question.

Comment: These are notices, not errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not initialize the quantities and prices. That is why you will get these errors. When you fill out new quantities and prices and then click the submit button you will be able to see the new prices and quantities in the $_POST global.

To avoid these errors you need to do the following: Before using the quantities and prices you need to check if they are initialized. You could do this with isset() function.

`if (isset($_POST['value']))

{

          // Instructions when $_POST['value'] does exist

}`